# To set thumbnail to a video file

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I want to set any Thumbnail image to the Video file. so, While I browse the video in Windows Explorer, I should be able to see the thumbnail (cover/poster image ) I have set. Is it possible. I see everywhere on net to extract frame from the Video. But, I want to "APPLY" a specific thumbnail to my video. Is it possible? Any Directshow or FFMPeg Solution? I was looking for some C# solution. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a video file feature. It's a Windows feature, it extracts the first non-black frame and shows it as a thumbnail in Windows Explorer. So you can do nothing with you video file, or you can add some frames into the beginning of video stream and hope they will be shown as thumbnail.

Comment: can we use GDI+ library to accomplish it?

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530538/ffmpeg-how-to-add-frames-or-black-at-the-end-of-a-video), or similar questions. I think GDI+ is not about processing video. Try to find some FFMpeg solution to add frames/video at the beginning of the file.